# For loop in Python with merging by rows pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function (`function_from_xml_pddataframe`) that takes xml files from `data` folder and transform to pandas dataframe called `df_xml`.

After this I need to create only one pandas dataframe (`all_dfs`) by merging them all by row.

This is what I did so far with a for loop:

```
import os
all_dfs = pd.DataFrame()

for file in tqdm("/data"):

    if file.endswith(".xml"):
      function_from_xml_pddataframe(xmlfile)
      
      df_created = df_xml
```

Comment: Create a list of dataframes by appending df_xml to the list inside the for loop, then pd.concat that list after the for loop.

Comment: @ScottBoston, thanks for your time.  This is exactly the idea. How I append df_xml to the list inside the loop?

Comment: Well it looks like @TitouanL has posted this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that all your DataFrames have the same columns, you can build a list in the for loop.

```
import os
list_of_dataframes = []

for file in tqdm("/data"):

    if file.endswith(".xml"):
        df_xml = function_from_xml_pddataframe(xmlfile)
        list_of_dataframes.append(df_xml)
      
all_dfs = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes)
```